# Is there any better and more suitable compiler for running basic graphics programs in c other than turbo c++?

Tags: c, graphics

I am trying to learn basic graphics programs in C and i want a more friendly and convenient compiler than turbo c which i am not able to find. Is there any better c compiler for graphics programs?

Comment: Any other compiler is better.

Comment: What is basic graphics? The one working in DOS only?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to use [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) for graphics programming. It is quite easy to use and allows you to draw simple shapes (circles, lines, rectangles, text, etc.)

Also you can easily set it up for modern IDE's such Visual Studio and Code Blocks.

Just google for " SDL setup" and you are good to go. Comment here if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I have followed your advice and tried to install SDL2 but i am still not able to run programs and getting stuck. Also i am very confused about how to actually set it up because there are many different tutorials online and i am not sure if i did it right. Please help